# jquery accessing children() value (using .html())

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, children

I have webpage that - by clicking a button - will dynamically create iframe which holds editable text field (CKE Editor). I need to access that edited text when one clicks another button (that html() is then send to SQLite DB later etc.).

This is my HTML (inside PHP file) structure from the iframe part onward (this is actual generated HTML text - copied from Firebug extension for Firefox - tho simplified by me just for this purpose):

```
<iframe class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="sk" dir="ltr">
        <head>//SOME OTHER TAGS HERE...not important for this problem</head>
        <body class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr>
        //SOME EDITABLE TEXT HERE...this is what I need to access!
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

I have this jQuery code by which I am trying to access that body html value created dynamically once again by PHP like this (as I guess I tried every possible way I have found I stripped it down for my testing purposes just to alert() to see if it gives me the value or not):

```
echo 'alert(jQuery("iframe[class*=\'cke_wysiwyg_frame\']").children("html").children("body").html());';
```

When I use this all I get is "null" in alert() window tho that first part jQuery("iframe[class*=\'cke_wysiwyg_frame\']") works OK - tested, it finds the right iframe...

So as I was desperate I also tryed several other ways like these once below according to other stackowerflow topic I have found:

```
echo 'alert(jQuery("iframe[class*=\'cke_wysiwyg_frame\']").children().eq(0).children().eq(1).html());';

// OK with this I already know that get() is giving DOM object and should be nested in other jQuery(), anyway...
echo 'alert(jQuery("iframe[class*=\'cke_wysiwyg_frame\']").children().get(0).children().get(1).html());';

echo 'alert(jQuery("iframe[class*=\'cke_wysiwyg_frame\']").find("body").html());';
```

All of this is giving me "null" of "undefined" in alert() test window. For some reason I am simply not able access children() object, or at least do not know any functional way how to access it/them (cos according to alert() window when I just had (jQuery("iframe[class*=\'cke_wysiwyg_frame\']").children() it gives me [object Object] but that's it - there is no way I know to access it so I could move to next children()).

I also search the web where basically all somewhat relevant answers are pointing to StackOwerflow tho none of them actually work for me.

What do I do wrong here? I have no clue...unfortunately.

**EDIT**
[@A. Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff) YOUR ANSWER IS THE RIGHT ONE - please, can you post your answer as standalone message so I can flag it as the right answer?

Comment: How the content of iframe is loaded? You should bind onload event of iframe (if needed) and from there access its content, using e.g: `$(this).contents().find("body").html()`

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot as that whole part from iframe onward (and even some more tags before them) are made by CKE Editor own huge minified scripts that I do not want to edit/mess around...

Comment: As A. Wolff mentioned, to get the `document` object of an iframe using jQuery, use the `contents()` method. But, if you're using CKEditor, then you should be able to get the data by calling `CKEDITOR.instances.instanceName.getData();`

Comment: @Rafael oh, I nver knew that ther eis such an option (you know I just grab that nice script and make it work for me not studying it properly) - I will definitely look into that CKEDITOR option, thanx + I am going to try that .contents() right now

Comment: @Wolff SUPERB - that .contents() actually did the trick...that was the part i was unaware of...thank you so much! Would you please make your answer as standalone message so I can flag it as the right answer?

Comment: @errerr Please take a look at this link http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_savedata it describes alternative ways of getting/saving CKEditor data.

Comment: @Rafael thank you for the link, I will look into it

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML).</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanx for your solution but I already have one, Wolff's one but he needs to post it as separate message, not comment as he did so I can set it as the right answer